# Como trabalhar com boletos na API PHP do Pagar.me

Tags: php

Minha dificuldade está em fazer o parsing dos dados retornados na geração do boleto. Meu objetivo é pegar este dado e fazer algumas transformações, como formatar a data/hora e algumas outras mudanças como tradução do status do boleto, etc.

Meus métodos de geração de boleto e consulta:

```
/**
 * Gera um boleto para pagamento
 * 
 * @param int       $valor
 * @param array     $dados
 * @param string    $urlCallBack
 * @param array     $metadados
 * @return          void
 */
public function gerar($valor, $dados, $urlCallBack = null, $metadados = null)
{
    $customer = new Customer($dados);

    return $this->pagarMe->transaction()->boletoTransaction(
                $valor,
                $customer,
                $urlCallBack,
                $metadados
            );
}

/**
 * Retorna os dados do boleto
 * 
 * @return \PagarMe\Sdk\Transaction\BoletoTransaction
 */
public function consultar(int $transacaoId)
{
    return $this->dicionario($this->pagarMe->transaction()->get($transacaoId));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
    $res = TuaClasse->gerar(1000, \PagarMe\Sdk\Customer\Customer $customer, $urlCallBack = null, $metadados = null)

    $id_da_transacao = $res->getId();
?>
```